# GDAL Open ZIP returns None

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to open Sentinel-2 bands directly from the .zip L2A files with GDAL, but this only returns a None. Unzipping the folder prior to reading the file yield better results, but still randomly returns some None from time to time. I'm using gdal 2.2.2.

```
import numpy as np 
import osgeo.gdal as gdal
import zipfile, os

from libs.generic import filemanager as fm
os.environ['CPL_ZIP_ENCODING'] = 'UTF-8'

class s2img:

def __init__(self):
    return None

def readL2A(self, zippath):

    try:
        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zippath, 'r')
    except:
        raise IOError("Unable to open ZIP-file.")

    flist = zipf.namelist()
    zipf.close()

    bandnames = []
    bandnames.append( ['B02','B03','B04','B08'] )
    bandnames.append( ['B05','B06','B07','B8A','B11','B12','SCL'] )
    bandnames.append( ['B01','B09'] )

    bandres = ['10m','20m','60m']

    fnames = [f for f in flist if 'IMG_DATA' in f]
    fnames = [f for f in fnames if f.endswith('.jp2')]
    for r in range(len(bandnames)-1):
        res = bandres[r]
        resbnames = bandnames[r]
        fresnames = [f for f in fnames if res in f]

        for b in range(len(resbnames)):
            fname= [f for f in fresnames if resbnames[b] in f ][0]
            chn_fn = "/vsizip/%s/%s" % (zippath,fname)
            gobj = gdal.Open(chn_fn, gdal.GA_ReadOnly )

            # DO STUFF 
    return None
```

Comment: Could you give a link for getting some test data? Have you tried to read data from the zip with gdalinfo or gdal_translate?

Comment: @user30184 here's an example file: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12TpPKjnrBCDaox12REFMhLPbH6p449t6)
I use neither of the two options. I'd like to make a standalone python scipt and from what i found in the documentation, those methods can only be used through command line or with the C API, right?

Comment: It does not matter if your final aim is to do it with Python. If you test reading data from zip with gdalinfo or gdal_translate and test is successful then you'll know that it is possible and all that is left is to do it right with Python.

Comment: I suggest to study the Python autotests in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gdrivers/sentinel2.py. I am not familiar with Sentinel2 format which seems a bit complicated. Gdalinfo behaves as supposed directly from zip with your example data.

Comment: @user30184 thank you for your reply. After running without success some bits of the code you linked, I tried to simply read an unzipped jpeg2000 band, still without success. This is odd since on my other pc, with the same python modules/libraries this worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. In order for gdal to be able to properly read the "sentinel-2.jp2" bands it needs supporting files. The location of the these can be specified by properly setting the "GDAL_DATA" environment variable: (https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQInstallationAndBuilding#HowtosetGDAL_DATAvariable)

If you're using Ananconda as the python library manager, then at the beginning of your script you should insert a line like this:

```
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = "C:/Users/B/Anaconda3/Library/share/gdal"
```

If you're using a virtual environment then the path should look something like this:

`os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = "C:/Users/B/Anaconda3/envs/geopy/Library/share/gdal/"`,

where "geopy" is the name of my environment.

However, this doesn't explain why on my other pc I didn't need to add this line to the code in order for the script to run properly on already unzipped images.